# Bluetooth seems to not be working properly in windows after dual booting to Garuda Linux

Tags: windows, bluetooth, garuda-linux

So, today I decided to try out Garuda Linux. After being a little experienced with simpler Linux distros like 'Ubuntu', 'Raspbian', Mainly attracted by its looks, I decided to try out this Arch-Linux based 'Garuda Linux Dragonized'.

After dual-booting it everything seemed to work smoothly, until I ran into 3 problems:

1. Bluetooth problems on Windows 10 21H1
2. Microphone not working in Garuda
3. Time in Windows changes every time I boot back into it.
   But most importantly, I need my bluetooth connectivity issues fixed on Windows.

Any possibilities or help?
System Specs:
CPU - AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS
RAM - 16GB
SSD - 1TB nVME
Bluetooth and Wifi Card - MediaTek.

I looked up a lot online, but none helped.

Any help is largely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you loaded any updates into Windows recently? ;)

Comment: Um no. Not upgrading to windows 11 anytime soon though. Uninstalled Garuda Linux, attempting to install into an external hard-drive and then try to boot through it rather than booting through primary storage.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the part on the download page that said:-

- Dual booting Garuda Linux may lead to unexpected issues! Be aware that the other OS may change the EFI boot priorities on UEFI or overwrite the bootloader on BIOS systems.

Apart from it not making sense (...the **other OS** may change the EFI boot priorities...)

It seems to be a warning not to use it in dual boot situations, at least that is how I would read it.

Always read the install instructions.

Comment: Yes, I realized it too late. Sadly, had to uninstall it. Wish it was more compatible with dual booting. Do you have any other simpler Linux distros that are similar to Garuda Linux in looks and is compatible with dual booting?

Comment: The time "problem" will always be present as Windows stores time differently.
 I would choose a distro that has a history of development over a period of several years, is reasonably popular [ has a large community ] and a good level of stability. But your choice will be different - especially if you choose a bleeding-edge distro.

Comment: Should I go for Ubuntu straight up?

Comment: On what basis do you want to choose? Ubuntu and their locked-down app store irritate me. Personally, I would try LMDE (for extra stability) or Mint as they are both very configurable, although the defaults are good. Note that this would be my **personal** choice.

Comment: Like, I just want it to look beautiful. The main reason I even stood up for Garuda Linux is its UI and its looks. The KDE Plasma desktop seemed well and so was the performance.
Ubuntu seemed simple in looks and Mint gives me this 'Windows' like vibes. I'm a person who is more keen to try something new .

Comment: If you want KDE, then look at the suggestions in `https://kde.org/distributions/`.